# Why does my WordPress site have index.php in URL?

Tags: wordpress, url

I am developing a website using WordPress. When you go to pages, it displays a `index.php` in the URL before the page name.

For example:

```
http://hci2018.bcs.org/index.php/register/
```

But it should be

```
http://hci2018.bcs.org/register/
```

How do I remove the `index.php`?

Comment: What are the inner page structure like ?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Permalinks of the site:

1. Go to Setting in the admin
2. and click on the permalink
3. Change the permalink to post name

You can get the exact URL as you want.

Comment: Hi Ranjit, I did this but then the pages were coming up as not found?

Comment: Please check the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. After enabling permalink to post name, all my pages (other than the homepage) came up as not found (404). This happened because the .htaccess file couldn't be modified by Wordpress.
I had to manually edit/modify the .htaccess file from the root folder of the website with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

After I did this, everything worked as before. And no more index.php before the page name. Problem solved!